# FreeBSD package installer (pkg) upgraded and I missed a library upgrade -pkg not working anymore -how can I fix this?

Tags: pkg-config

I was trying to install another package (wget) and It seems I got myself into a catch22 situation,
In order to install wget the system (a firewall-PFSense) required to upgrade pkg
It did ask me about upgrading libssl.so but I missed that and went ahead. So now pkg is not working anymore and I am looking for a way to go back to pkg 1.19.1_2 and redo the upgrdade correctly
Any idea how I can fix this ?

```
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
Fetching meta.conf: 100%    163 B   0.2kB/s    00:01    
Fetching packagesite.pkg: 100%    7 MiB   6.9MB/s    00:01    
Processing entries:   0%
Newer FreeBSD version for package zziplib:
To ignore this error set IGNORE_OSVERSION=yes
- package: 1400097
- running kernel: 1400085
Ignore the mismatch and continue? [y/N]: y
Processing entries: 100%
FreeBSD repository update completed. 34000 packages processed.
All repositories are up to date.
New version of pkg detected; it needs to be installed first.
The following 1 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be UPGRADED:
        pkg: 1.19.1_2 -> 1.20.7 [FreeBSD]

Number of packages to be upgraded: 1

The process will require 7 MiB more space.
11 MiB to be downloaded.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: y
[1/1] Fetching pkg-1.20.7.pkg: 100%   11 MiB  11.2MB/s    00:01    
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
[1/1] Upgrading pkg from 1.19.1_2 to 1.20.7...
[1/1] Extracting pkg-1.20.7: 100%
You may need to manually remove /usr/local/etc/pkg.conf if it is no longer needed.
ld-elf.so.1: Shared object "libssl.so.30" not found, required by "pkg"
.
[2.7.0-RELEASE][admin@mylab.net]/root: pkg install wget
ld-elf.so.1: Shared object "libssl.so.30" not found, required by "pkg"
```

Comment: Probably best to ask on [unix.se] or [su]. Stack Overflow is for *programming* q&a.

Answer (score 0):

I had to force remove pkg and reinstall the right version from the local cache